# How to do the accumulation with sas

Tags: sas

The question is there are males and females and among all these people there are drinkers and not drinkers. Now we wanna know the number of male who drinks or doesn't drink as well as the number of female who drinks or doesn't drink. The female is "2" and male is "1". Drinker is "1" and not drinker is "2". This is my code:

```
data depress;
set "C:\Users\Air\Desktop\652\depress.sas7bdat";
retain num1 0;
retain num2 0;
retain num3 0;
retain num4 0;
if (SEX=2 and DRINK=1) then do; num1=sum(num1,1);
if (SEX=2 and DRINK=2) then do; num2=sum(num2,1);
if (SEX=1 and DRINK=1) then do; num3=sum(num3,1);
if (SEX=1 and DRINK=2) then do; num4=sum(num4,1);
num5=num1+num2;
num6=num3+num4;
num7=num1+num3;
num8=num2+num4;
"num1 is ", num1;
"num2 is ", num2;
"num3 is ", num3;
"num4 is ", num4;
```

There is an error in it and I can't figure out what's wrong with these codes.

Comment: You've got lots of mistakes (missing END statement for each DO loop, the last 4 statements are invalid syntax, you probably mean `put "Num1 is " num1 ;`).  There should be errors in your log pointing to these problems.  If you really want to do this counting in a DATA step you can, e.g. `if (sex=2 and drink=1) then FemaleDrinkerCount+1;` but agree with @superfluous, PROC FREQ is for counting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you forgot the *run* statement in your code, but you're also over-complicating the problem.

Check out the *freq* procedure; it does exactly what you want:

```
proc freq data = depress noprint;
    tables gender * drinker / nopercent norow nocol sparse
    out = output;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.